# How can I attach event handlers to Square up credit card entry fields

Tags: iframe, square, square-connect

I'm working on a web based app that uses Square to process credit card payments. Square provides a javascript library that replaces the text input form elements in my form with iFrames. The rest of my form uses onchange handlers to verify the data and change the background color of the form when there is an error.

I would like to use local javascript to validate the credit card check digit and other entries with regex and such.

So my question is, can I attach even handlers to the Square iframe based input controls?

Comment: We do some credit card validation on our side, what specifically are you trying to do? In general we prevent your code from being able to access the raw credit card numbers.

Comment: I wanted to run the luhn check client side, and also be more restrictive about the expiration date. If I have no access to the credit card number I guess all that is out.

Comment: After generating a nonce you get things like the card brand and expiration date, maybe you could use that?

Comment: Well the idea was to avoid unnecessary calls to your API, both to improve customer experience and reduce load on your resources. But it looks like I'm stuck with it. Thanks for your quick reply on a weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you don't have access to the credit card number to implement your own number validation.

Comment: Hi @tristansokol . Has there been any fix for this? Or is there still not a way for developers to have error validation? I ask because I'd like to re-enable my "Submit payment" button only when a valid card has been inputted. And disable it otherwise.

Comment: I'm not at square any more, but I don't think you are ever going to get access to the card number (by design). It looks ilke with the new web payments SDK you can subscribe to events that trigger when the error classes add/remove and you could probably use that to enable disable your button https://developer.squareup.com/reference/sdks/web/payments/card-payments#Card.addEventListener.eventType